# How to handle intents with parameters on SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am trying to implement voice interaction on iOS with SwiftUI and Siri. I am just trying to get a shortcut to work with a single string parameter. I am very new to the framework and have been stuck. Below is what I tried:

- Started on the Scrumdinger project (from an Apple SwiftUI tutorial, which I have in a GitHub repo. I stopped at commit [90731](https://github.com/ataias/Scrumdinger/commit/907318b9d11d88a5ccde4b9f2d40b4f8d05d89e6) before any Siri updates)
- Created a button to add a Siri shortcut based on NSUserActivity to create a new scrum, but without any parameters; this worked ([d64133](https://github.com/ataias/Scrumdinger/commit/d64133bd5f40759b0dff405b5673f2ea3268e858))
- Afterwards, I tried a bunch of things that didn't work:

  - Created an intent extension target with a group to share
  - Created an intent with a parameter, naming it "ScrumIntent"
  - Created a shortcut for the intent
  - Requested authorization for Siri

Currently, my set up has all the above and I can create the shortcut, which appears on the shortcuts app. However, it gets stuck and I don't even know how to debug it. If I try voice, Siri complains something went wrong. If I try to click on the shortcut, it is also stuck. Below you can see an image of how it gets stuck, with a stop button almost mid complete.

[image]

I am trying to simply set a string in user defaults when the callback gets handled. No special checking on the handler.

Some points about the implementation:

- The handler is only in the extension target, but I am not sure if that's correct. In SwiftUI we can use the modifier `onContinueUserActivity` for NSUserActivities, but I couldn't find a similar one for intents (I understood we need intents for parameters).
- The "Add Siri shortcut" button simply defines the Intent and sets `suggestedInvocationPhrase`.

Is there any other detail or essential piece of code I should share here? I was not sure so I just shared the github links for now.